# What happens to a Demon or Elemental when their service term comes to an end?

Tags: exalted, exalted-3e

I can't find anything in the third edition about what happens to a summoned demon or elemental when their service term is over. Looking for any reference to what happens? Do they immediately return to where they came from? Or are they free to do what they want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's not explicitly stated for summoned Demons, it is stated for Elementals on page 476, in the rules for *Summon Elemental*

(Emphasis mine)

> **Summon Elemental**

> ...Once summoned, the elemental must be ***bound to the sorcerer’s will, as per Demon of the First Circle (p. 473)***, except that an elemental cannot break free—if the binding fails, the elemental simply disperses back into raw Essence, and the sorcerer doesn’t regain the Willpower spent on the spell. ***At the end of a bound elemental’s term of service or assigned task, it usually undergoes the same fate of dissipation***, although elementals who have developed a fully-formed personality and identity may persist past the end of their binding at the Storyteller’s discretion. Summon Elemental can only be cast once per day.

Admittedly, it's a little ambiguous as to the "same fate", if it is referring to summoned demons or the dispersion on a failure.